# How to prevent a derived class object under base class pointer calling a public nonvirtual function defined in base class but overridden in derived?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Suppose base class `B` has a nonvirtual public function `f()` , which is unfortunately overridden by derived class `D`.

Then there's a `D` object `d` passed to a `B` pointer `pB`.

Is there a way to prevent calling `pB->f()`?

Comment: Is the question "how to prevent people from trying to override that function" ? In that case, that should be caught on their side when they declare `D`'s function as `override`.

Comment: You cannot override a non-virtual function.

Comment: @KerrekSB - "cannot override a non-virtual function". sudden attack of pedantry, eh? Be a nice guy and explain to the OP what you mean. Or be cryptical but provide a positive alternative to your negation, as in "You can sometimes hide, but you can't override"

Comment: If you know it’s a D and not a B, you can cast pB to a D&.  You can check whether it is using RTTI.

Comment: @Lorehead: You can't necessarily use RTTI if `B` doesn't have virtual functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB In that case, yeah, you’re out of luck.  You might be able to do some other rigmarole where you can determine by calling B’s interface that something is in fact a D, but the question seems to amount to, “How do I make this function virtual?”

Comment: I suspect casting is the only way. The compiler can't know what type is being pointed to without either virtual dispatch or casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change `B`, you can either make `f` virtual, or make it forward to a virtual protected `do_f`, or various other things.

If you can't change `B`, you can't stop it's public method being called, and you can't somehow intercept a call to a non-virtual base class method.

Comment: Your second phrase: the syntax is correct, but it hardly parses to a meaning. Care to rephrase please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question essentially asks, “How do I make a function virtual?”  You don’t give a reason why you can’t just do that, but maybe you can’t change the declaration of `B`.

If `B` has at least one virtual function, you could use RTTI to check if `*pB` is really a `D` and cast it to `D&` if so.  You cannot make existing code that takes a `B*` do so; if your daughter class breaks when you call it as a `B`, it breaks the contract of that interface.

Otherwise, it might be possible to determine that `*pB` is a `D` somehow by calling the `B` interface, but that would be some rigmarole specific to `B` and `D`.